# CS0103: The name 'CType' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, compilation, ctype

I have the following markup in my .aspx page:

```
<ul>
            <li><asp:HyperLink ID="lnkHome" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" runat="server" /></li>
            <asp:Repeater id="navRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="SMDS1" EnableViewState="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# CType(Container.DataItem, SiteMapNode).ChildNodes %>'>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </ul>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
```

And when I try to compile it I get this:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service >this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source >code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'CType' does not exist in the current context

I literally got this code right off of the MSDN website. Has anyone any idea why it would be giving me this issue? Site is in C#, if that information helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently, CType is a Visual Basic Thing.

```
((SiteMapNode)Container.DataItem).ChildNodes
```

fixed.

Comment: Well crafted and self answered question :)